# A block in beamer

Tags: beamer

I am unable to understand why this is not compiling,

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}{}
  \begin{block}
    $$\phi (S) \geq \lambda (1 - \sqrt {C \delta})$$
  \end{block}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

- Can someone help?

Comment: The above code has no problem and works with me. Please post a complete MWE instead of code snippets to help us help you find the problem. I edited the code which works with me. Do you have any problem compiling that?

Comment: I just added `\documentclass{beamer} \begin{document}` ... `\end{document}` which works with me. Do you have any problem compiling that?

Comment: does it work on overleaf?

Comment: It doesn't work on overleaf.

Comment: Add `{}` after `\begin{block}`. And never use `$$` in LaTeX.

Comment: But $$ for centering a maths equation has never giiven troubles. Whats the issue here?

Comment: But without $$ what else to use?

Comment: It is 20 years out of date. Use `\[\]` instead. @AboAmmar Does it really compile for you without error? It doesn't work on TeX Live.

Comment: Interesting! Never heard of this!

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to

Answer (score 2):

The `block` environment expects a title. You can have it be empty, but it needs to be there:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}{}
    \begin{block}{}
    \[\phi (S) \geq \lambda (1 - \sqrt {C \delta})\]
    \end{block}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

It has only to do with an empty `{}` after the `\begin{block}` even without a title. As another hack, you can only insert an empty line after `\begin{block}`. So this works:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}{}
  \begin{block}{}
    \[\phi (S) \geq \lambda (1 - \sqrt {C \delta})\]
  \end{block}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Also this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}{}
  \begin{block}

    \[\phi (S) \geq \lambda (1 - \sqrt {C \delta})\]
  \end{block}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```